# Angular Schematics vs Library

Tags: angular

I'm starting a project with friends, which is based on angular. We are not sure whats the correct way to provide functionalities which are common in some repositories.

Is it common to use code generation (schematics) to provide components with template and typescript codes) or is it common to use libraries?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing code (i.e. components, services, pipes, etc) are typically done with [libraries](https://angular.io/guide/libraries). Schematics are generally used when you, for example, want to automate steps that a user normally would have to do manually in order to use your library.